# Google Analytics API Quota Exceeded Discrepancy

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am getting a 53% error rate on our requests but we are well under all of the quotas.

Our current quota limits are:
Queries per day - 50,000
Queries per 100 seconds per user - 1,000
Queries per 100 seconds - 2,000

There is clearly a discrepancy between numbers they are showing and the behavior of the API. Even if we add up daily usage for 2 days in a row, it's still under 50k

Also when we check the request rate during the time when the errors occur it's only 0.2 requests per second.

It appears to be happening around the same time each night.

Does this look familiar to anyone?

[image: screenshot of cloud console]

Comment: daily quotes work on a per project and per view level. have you reviewed both to them?

Comment: Sal is correct,   There are limits per view and project. See the v3 quota limit https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas  and the v4 quota limits docs https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas . I'm guessing you are hitting the queries per view limit of view 10,000 .